# Is there any open source implementation of APL?

Tags: open-source, apl

I am aware of J & K; but neither are open source.

I'm also aware of A+, but that seems outdated.

Is there any decent open source implementation of APL?

If so, where? If not, why?

Comment: Possibly a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887521/apl-versus-a-versus-j-versus-k

Comment: GNU APL was released a week or two ago: https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/

Comment: J is open-source now: http://www.jsoftware.com/source.htm

Answer (score 6):

I'm experimenting with an APL interpreter in JavaScript (http://github.com/ngn/apl), runs on node.js or in a browser.  It can do basic stuff, like compute a generation of Conway's game of life, but it's early to tell if it can turn out into a decent implementation.

Answer (score 5):

You might try NARS2000 (at http://www.nars2000.org/). I've not tried it myself so can't comment on how it compares to the commercial interpreters.

Answer (score 5):

[Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona) is an open-source ascii based APL, inspired from K.

Answer (score 5):

[J7](http://jsoftware.com/source.htm) was recently released under the GPL.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [OpenAPL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openapl)?

It is open source.

Answer (score 1):

There's [J](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_(programming_language)).

Comment: You can buy the source at crazy rates, at which point it is open to you.  </sarcasm>

Comment: Yup.  Open Source doesn't necessarily mean free.

Comment: "open-source software must comply with the following criteria:
1. Free Redistribution" http://opensource.org/docs/osd

Comment: OSI's definition of "open source software" isn't universally accepted.

Comment: Just a year after this answer, J was released under GPL v3! https://github.com/jsoftware/jsource

Answer (score 1):

I have just discovered a Javascript implementation of APL here:

https://github.com/ngn/apl

Comment: see the previous answer here by ngn for more....