# Which is the best (and free) APL interpreter?

Tags: interpreter, apl

I need an [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29) implementation to test some expressions, do your know which is the best interpreter for the language ?

It would be great if it is free and it runs on Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2135108/4098326

Answer (score 15):

You can test simple expressions with my APL interpreter, it runs on JavaScript in the browser: http://ngn.github.com/apl/web/index.html

EDIT: I've moved on from APL and now I recommend learning K instead. I made a partial re-implementation of K6 in C at https://codeberg.org/ngn/k/

Comment: Looks great and very intuitive

Comment: A few issues, but this is pretty good work. :-)

Comment: I agree. Way better than tryapl.

Comment: Well, thank you :)  A bold statement, considering the fact that behind tryapl runs Dyalog, the best (albeit commercial) APL implementation out there.

Comment: @ngn, how do I assign a matrix to a variable? Say 2x2 matrix?

Comment: Also, i can't seem to find the division operator.. % doesn't work!

Comment: @l19 You can create a matrix using the "reshape" verb (rho), for instnce: `2 2 ⍴ 11 12 21 22`.  Check out the first example.

Comment: You can assign anything to a variable using the "copula", `←`.

Unlike J, APL uses `÷` for division; that's the "obelus" symbol which you can find on calculators.  I think Iverson later picked `%` for J because it is the ASCII symbol which most looks like `÷`.

By the way, in my project I didn't bother to document the language.  If you google around, you can find some decent introductory material on it.

Comment: Thanks @ngn! Two things though: your interpreter doesn't have the `÷` on the keyboard, and the inner product of matrices (`+.x`) doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed.  It underwent a major rewrite in the past month.  Most of it should work, but don't expect it to be 100% complete.

Comment: @ngn The partitioned enclose(`⊂`) works slightly weirdly, if you go by the [Dyalog Help](http://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/Primitive%20Functions/Partitioned%20Enclose.htm)

Answer (score 8):

Try [GNU APL](http://www.gnu.org/software/apl/).  Version 1.0 was released September 27, 2013.

Answer (score 5):

Also, if you want to try something, why not go to http://tryapl.org ? :)
And, finally, [Dyalog Ltd.](http://dyalog.com) offers free version of their interpreter *(the best you can get, IMHO*) - which is free for personal, non-commercial use - which sounds like what you do..
And while TryAPL gives you a protected environment in which certain "potentially harmful" statements are not allowed, there is a new service available which gives you a complete sandboxed Dyalog APL environment that can execute scripted commands at https://tio.run/#apl-dyalog

Comment: Update: Dyalog is available for Windows, Linux, MacOS and AIX.

Answer (score 2):

Try APLX for Linux (Personal Edition) Version 1.1 from [MicroAPL.](http://www.microapl.co.uk/apl/aplx_downloads.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best for PC are>

APL2 IBM but free only a trial period.

APLX is very good but some different to APL2.seems to be Eternal Life inside APL.

Comment: "Free for a trial period" is a trial. So it's not free but rather commercial. Is APLX free?